# How to use a fixed-length array when number of user inputs are unknown

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to take user input for an item, the Qty, and the Cost.  The user can input any number of items.  My issue is that the assignment says:

Input: Use a loop to garner user input from the console using java.util.Scanner and place the input into a fixed-length array.

The part that trips me up is I don't understand how I can set the length of the array when I don't know how many user inputs there will be.   I've searched for an answer but haven't found anything that answered, or if it did it didn't click for me.   I was hoping an example of a simple solution where one could get an unknown number of inputs into an array.

Comment: The typical way of solving this is to add the elements to a `List`, and then call `List#toArray` when the user input is finished.

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible that the problem implies the user first provides the number of inputs as the first input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming here that input will be in integer form only and the user provides an item, qty and cost in term of an integer. In that case, we can use list to store the user-input and after that, we can use a fixed-length array to store all the inputs.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();  
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        list.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    int[] store = new int[list.size()];
    int k=0;
    for(int i:list){
        store[k++]=i;
    }
```

(If a user is giving input in string format then you can just change sc.nextInt() to sc.nextLine() and using substring() you can extract all the inputs.)

For example,
1 10 100
2 20 200
---------- List will store all these 6 values and then it will create the array of size 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList<>, it's almost the same as a simple array, but has no fixed-length. If you have "fixed-length" as part of the task, then you may copy an array to the new one with doubled size after the current is filled up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making an array length i. When another thing is input is entered make a new array length i + 1 leaving you with a space for another input. You can continue adding one more space everytime another input is made